# Add new column to multi nested array in mongo db

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

```
"ParentType": {
    "Food": [
      {
        "Name": "Burger",
        "FoodId": "5e3abe145c1bfb31b4e335de",
        "Price": 0,
        "Quantity": 1,
        "SubCategory": 0
      }
    ],
    "Inventory": [
      {
        "Name": "Small Popcorn",
        "InventoryId": "5e3a64245c1bfb31b4e335b7",
        "Price": 0,
        "Quantity": 1,
        "SubCategory": 0
      }
    ]
  }
```

I need to add UOM as new column only for Inventory array.I have used aggregate as below but collection is not getting updated.Pls help me with adding this new Column in mongodb

```
 db.Concession.aggregate([   
    {
      $addFields: { ParentType.Inventory.UOM: "null" }
    }
])
```

Comment: The aggregate query **just for showing the query output result only** but won't update the result into the collection. Either you need [`$merge`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) / [`$out`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-out) stage to add the result of aggregation pipeline into collection or you need the update query. [`db.collection.update()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

Answer (score 0):

add UOM to all eliment in Inventory

```
db.collection.update( 
   {},
   { $set: { 'ParentType.Inventory.$[].UOM':''} }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: ( Update/$set 3.6+ )**

```
db.collection.update({},
{
 $set: {
   "ParentType.Inventory.$[].UOM": null
 }
},
{
 multi: true
})
```

Explained:

1. Use update() operation with positional operator [$[]](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) ( mongoDB 3.6+ )
2. Use option multi to update all documents in collection matching the filter criteria

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iXH4vEr6AXc)

**Option 2: ( Update/aggregation 4.2+)**

```
db.collection.update({},
[
 {
  $addFields: {
  "ParentType.Inventory": {
    "$map": {
      input: "$ParentType.Inventory",
      as: "i",
      in: {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$$i",
          {
            UOM: null
          }
        ]
      }
     }
   }
  }
 }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Explained:

1. Use update with [aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) ( mongoDB 4.2+ )
2. In aggregation use the addFileds with mergeObjects so you add the new fields to the array element.
3. Use multi:true to affect all documents in collection matching the filter criteria

[Playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kQZppddA06e)